# how to publish flv file using ffmpeg to RTMP server in `real time`?

Tags: ffmpeg, red5, rtmp

what i'm trying to do is publishing a `.flv` media file to `RTMP` server to let subscribers watch it.
i'm testing to view the stream in several subscribers (the `oflaDemo`) and with `ffplay`.

the problem is that ffmpeg publish the 5 minutes .flv file to the server in nearly 20 seconds, in these 20 seconds the stream appear on subscribes, but after that it cuts.
the command i use is:

```
ffmpeg -i file.flv -re -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv "rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/aaa live=1"
```

how can i force `ffmpeg` to stream the 5 minutes file in 5 minutes, or any other solution.

thanks.

Comment: I believe `-re` should be used as an input option, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

i **solved** it

the `-re` should be the first parameter:

```
ffmpeg -re -i file.flv -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/a3
```

from [ffmpeg official documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

> The generic syntax is:

```
ffmpeg [global options] [[infile options][‘-i’ infile]]... {[outfile options] outfile}...
```

> -re **(input)**
>
> Read input at native frame rate. Mainly used to simulate a grab
>   device. By default ffmpeg attempts to read the input(s) as fast as
>   possible. This option will slow down the reading of the input(s) to
>   the native frame rate of the input(s).....

the docs says that `-re` option is input flag which means that it should be in `infile options` directly before the `-i` flag

Comment: I am trying the same thing: Red5 as server, and ffmpeg feeds the stream, and use ffplay or VLC to view the stream. Now I cannot view the stream! How do you do that? Thanks!